# contenteditable and emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a contentEditable view that when i focusOut i get the html entered and save it.

But when i remove all text from the contenteditable and then focus out i get the error

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.
```

Please see this jsfiddle and delete the value1 text and focus out.

http://jsfiddle.net/rmossuk/Q2kAe/8/

Can anyone help with this ?

best regards
Rick

Comment: sounds to me like it may be a bug. You could try reporting it on github https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues especially since you have a fiddle that can reproduce it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `EditableView` sets up a display binding to its `content.value`:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="editable"> 
   {{view.content.value}}
</script>
```

Ember performs its binding-updating magic by wrapping the relevant parts with marker script tags. Have a look at the resulting DOM:

[image: Ember display binding script tags]

Now you make your view editable. As soon as the user completely deletes the view's contents you will notice that the surrounding script tags are also removed (by the browser). At the moment Ember tries to update the display it won't find the necessary script tags and thus complains.

I don't think that you can make this approach to work reliably with `contenteditable`, since you won't be able to control the browser leaving the Ember surroundings intact. I guess you will need to take care of the view updating yourself: remove the binding, create a `content.value` observer and update the DOM explicitly:

```
App.EditableView = Em.View.extend({
    contenteditable: "true",
    attributeBindings: ["contenteditable"],

    _observeContent: (function() {
        this._displayContent();
    }).observes('content.value'),

    didInsertElement: function() {
        this._displayContent();
    },
    _displayContent: function() {
        this.$().html(this.get('content.value'));
    },
    ...
```

Here is a JSFiddle with a demo of this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/green/BEtzb/2/.

(You could of course also use an `Ember.TextField` which uses a regular input field and provides all the binding magic, if that's all you need.)

Comment: thanks Julian D.       I was doing it like that before but was trying to see if i could use ember to keep up to date instead of updating the content myself.     I will go back to your solution!